# Converting class to functional component while using interface

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I've the below code. How can I convert it from class component to functional component, minding that I would like to use interface instead of type?
As well, I believe the empty type Props is not needed, right?

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

type Props = {};
type State = {
  hasError: boolean;
  guid: string;
};

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
      guid: uuidv4(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <>Error</>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an ErrorBoundary as described in the docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html -- If so, `Only class components can be error boundaries.`

Answer (score 0):

This particular component could be written as a functional component like this.

```
import { useState, ReactNode } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  otherProp?: string;
};

type State = {
  hasError: boolean;
  guid: string;
};

const ErrorBoundary = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
    hasError: false,
    guid: uuidv4()
  });

  if (state.hasError) {
    return <p>Error</p>;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};

const MyComp = () => {
  return <ErrorBoundary>some content without error</ErrorBoundary>;
};

export default MyComp;
```

[image: Edit dreamy-lederberg-s2r5u]

---

#### Note

If you are trying to create [an `ErrorBoundary` as described in the react docs](http://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) -- note that *only class components can be used*.